# Compatibility conditions of spinors and Riemannian Metrics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, research-level, differential-geometry, spinors

I came across an interesting article by Montesinos (J. Geom. Phys. 2 (1985), no. 2, 145–153.). In it, he finds that spin structures (as lifts of $SO(4)$) are not compatible with all Riemannian metrics on a four-manifold. In other words, he finds there are no "universal spinors" which are compatible with all the possible Riemannian metrics.

I don't completely understand the article (specifically he is doing some spinor variations to prove his results which I am still working out), but I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with this result (or similar results) and can tell me about their physical significance.

The first thing I am thinking is this implies something about the compatibility between GR and QFT, since there would be some metrics that may solve the classical Einstein equations but which do not admit some kinds of quantum matter described by spinors.

Is that a shot in the dark? Can anyone give me a more concrete explanation of what this paper means?

Here is an INSPIRE link to the paper (http://inspirehep.net/record/232859?ln=en) but unfortunately I cannot find an open source one.

Comment: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure) ?

Comment: Yeah the wikipedia site mostly focuses on the topological restrictions - the vanishing of the Steifel-Whitney class - for a manifold to admit spin structures. But Montesinos worked on the opposite question - is there a spin structure which can be compatible with all the metrics? We get obstructions in both cases, but it seems like they should not be related.

Comment: Is Montesinos assuming that he's working on a spin manifold?  Because otherwise, this is a triviality.  Riemannian metrics are in 1-1 correspondence with $O(n)$-structures, some of which are neither orientable nor spin orientable.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is that if spacetime (or space) is non-orientable, you are unable to define a spinor bundle because there's no special orthogonal frame bundle (although you still have an orthogonal bundle, so you can do some spin-ish thing, I guess).

But that is unrelated to the metric. Can't really think of any good reason why the metric would forbid spinors.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm thinking there are some topological restrictions but I don't understand the metric stuff.